# Microsoft signtool removes administrative privileges?

Tags: exe, sign, administration

I need to sign an installer executable for Windows using a p12 file.

Before signing, this EXE file icon has a "shield icon" on it indicating that it requires administrative privileges, as it should.

However, after I sign using the signtool and the following command:

```
signtool.exe sign /f mycert.pfx /p <password> /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v "<file to be signed>"
```

the signing succeeds but the shield icon disappears. When I run the resulting executable, it fails because it is no longer running under administrative privileges.

What do I need to do in order to sign an executable and have it keep its administrative privileges?

Comment: Same issue here, have you solved it?

Comment: After further investigation it seems I misunderstood first tests results: adding the manifest file for admin privileges is removing digital sign, but adding digital sign is NOT removing the manifest, so it is enough to do actions in the proper order.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the requestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator in your app's manifest to declare it as needing administrative privileges.

I suspect that your app is named "install" or similar, and so the non signed-and-manifested version picked up the administrator requirement as part of backwards compatibility settings, but now it looks like a current application and so Windows checks to see which privileges it requests, and since it doesn't request any the app doesn't get elevated.

See [Create and Embed an Application Manifest with Your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx) 
Depending on how the app is created also look at [/MANIFESTUAC (Embeds UAC information in manifest)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) and [/win32manifest (C# Compiler Options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545961.aspx)

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks, but I don't think it's the filename. I can rename the file to anything I want, and the administrative privileges stick. Also, the executable is an installer built with an installer package that flags the executable as requiring administrative privileges, so I think it already does the request you mention.