# Issue with signing with Visual Studio For the Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, signtool

I have a Visual Studio 2015 C# Solution, it has about 8 assemblies and executable and some exes require elevated permission.  So I sign my executable and assemblies with a certificate on the post-build of each executable and assembly.  Then I sign them on the pre-build of the installer, and then I post-build my MSI.

As a result, the MSI is signed while the install, but the executable that requires elevated permission does not, and it has the same date and time as the MSI (just a second before).

Here is the script that I am using..

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\Work\source\Certificate\CodeSign.pfx /p xxxxpasswordxxxx /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 "c:\source\app\bin\Debug\app.exe"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: As per [Microsoft signtool removes administrative privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787393/microsoft-signtool-removes-administrative-privileges) I have set the requestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator in the app's manifest.

Comment: No, I already have done that.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing what VS does with the file, it adds the files to the OBJ folder, so I had to sign the file that was in the obj\debug folder on pre-compile, and it works.
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\Work\source\Certificate\CodeSign.pfx /p xxxxpasswordxxxx /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /td SHA256 "c:\source\app\obj\Debug\app.exe"